# android - Java throwing me FileNotFound exception HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http

I have a class with a static function to make a POST request to a web server. So far it was working for every request I've made, however I added a new .php file and it throws me a FileNotFound exception at the function call for the new script. I tested it through browser and Postman and the script works.

The class/function:

```
public class WebServices {
public static final String CONNECTION_URL = "http://192.168.1.101/klikniobrok/";
public static final String LOGIN = "login.php";
public static final String REGISTER = "register.php";
public static final String RESTAURANTS = "restaurant.php";
public static final String MENU = "menu.php";
public static final String MENU_ENTRIES = "menuentries.php";
public static final String EMPLOYEE_LOGIN = "employeelogin.php";
public static final String GET_TABLE = "table.php";
public static final String ADD_ORDER = "insertorder.php";
public static final String RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_ORDERS = "activeorders.php";
public static final String COMPLETE_ORDER = "completeorder.php";

public static JSONObject makeHttpPostRequest(List<Pair<String, String>> params, String action) {
    JSONObject requestResponse;
    try {
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        if(params != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) {
                    postData.append("&");
                }
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(i).first, "UTF-8"));
                postData.append("=");
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(i).second, "UTF-8"));
            }
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        URL connUrl = new URL(CONNECTION_URL + action);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) connUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(HttpMethods.POST);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        if(postDataBytes.length > 0) {
            connection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
        }
        BufferedReader requestInputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),
                "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder requestInput = new StringBuilder();
        for(String line = requestInputReader.readLine(); line != null; line = requestInputReader.readLine()) {
            requestInput.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        requestInputReader.close();
        connection.disconnect();
        requestResponse = new JSONObject(requestInput.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        requestResponse = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        requestResponse = null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        requestResponse = null;
    }
    return requestResponse;
}
```

And the exception:

```
    06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.101/klikniobrok/completeorder.php
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok.WebServices.makeHttpPostRequest(WebServices.java:59)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok.helpers.CompleteOrder.doInBackground(OrderProcessor.java:37)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok.helpers.CompleteOrder.doInBackground(OrderProcessor.java:31)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-10 00:09:52.606 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-10 00:09:52.607 12561-13302/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok.helpers.OrderProcessor.setOrderCompeted(OrderProcessor.java:164)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok.ActiveOrdersActivity$2.onClick(ActiveOrdersActivity.java:103)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5781)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
06-10 00:09:52.608 12561-12561/mk.klikniobrok.klikniobrok W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

The follow-up null pointer exception is a result to the first one.

The call to the function:

```
    class CompleteOrder extends AsyncTask<Pair<String, String>, Void, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Pair<String, String>... params) {
        return WebServices.makeHttpPostRequest(Arrays.asList(params), WebServices.COMPLETE_ORDER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        // other logic here
    }
}
```

As I stated, the function works for other 'actions', i.e when used for posting to other scripts. For example I am able to log-in just before I click the button that invokes the method. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileNotFoundException` occurred because the server gave you a `404 Not Found` response.

You need to look at the URL you used and/or the "error page" document returned by the server and/or the server-side logs to figure out why the server did that.

> As I stated, the function works for other 'actions', i.e when used for posting to other scripts

Obviously ... *something* is different.

Comment: To be precise, 404 is mapped to `FileNotFoundException` if you call `getInputStream()`. If you call `getResponseCode()` first, you will get 404, and you can read the error page via `getErrorStream()`.

Comment: Checked the server logs as you suggested, found the error there. Still getting used to PHP, I keep forgetting that execution errors can be found in the server logs.